# urlopen with timeout fails behind proxy

Tags: python, proxy, urlopen

python 2.7.3 under linux: getting strange behaviour when trying to use the timeout parameter

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError

url = "http://speedtest.website-solution.net/speedtest/random350x350.jpg"

try:
    #f = urlopen(url, timeout=30)   #never works - always times out
    f = urlopen(url)    #always works fine, returns after < 2 secs
    print("opened")
    f.close()
    print("closed")

except IOError as e:
    print(e)
    pass
```

EDIT:

Digging into this more, it seems lower level.. the following code has the same issue:

```
    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(30)
    s.connect(("speedtest.website-solution.net", 80))    #times out
    print("opened socket")
    s.close()
```

It's running behind a socks proxy. Running using `tsocks python test.py`. Wonder if that can be screwing up the socket timeout for some reason? Seems strange that `timeout=None` works fine though.

Comment: +1 for the concise, complete sample program. Your program works flawlessly on my PC using either call to `urlopen`. I have Ubuntu 13.10, Python 2.7.5. What OS are you using?

Comment: No good ideas; when you say it always times out, does it timeout after exactly the time you specified? If you set timeout(100) it takes 100 seconds to timeout?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yes - exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. figured it out. This is indeed related to the proxy. No idea why, but the following code seems to fix it:

Source: https://code.google.com/p/socksipy-branch/

Put this at the start of the code:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request, HTTPError, URLError
import httplib

import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "192.168.56.1", 101)
socks.wrapmodule(urllib2)
```

Now everything works fine..